# Backbone js instant search collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im trying to implement kind of an "instant search" on a collection. I pass a string to my search function and match it with the attribute "name" in my collection. But thing is that now it needs to be a perfect match to work. eg. you don't get any results if just part of the search term matching the "name" attribute. How would i fix that?

```
search: function(str) {
    var models = this.collection.where({name:str});
    var search = new PeopleCollection(models)

    new PeopleView({
        el: this.$('.peoplelist'),
        collection: search
    });
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var models = this.collection.filter(function(item) {
    return item.get("name").indexOf(str) > -1
});
```